# Необходимо построить график

Tags: python, графика

Только начинаю работать с анализом данных на питоне, появился вопрос:
У меня есть дф, первое поле которого это идентификатор, а второе - лист точек (x,y), а конкретнее что-то вроде [(1,6),(5,9)(4,7),(2,12),(5,14)...]
Как я могу построить зависимость х от у из этого всего?) То есть как мне перебрать все точки для каждого идентификатора?

Comment: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060)

Answer (score 0):

Смотря какой график нужен.
Во многих случаях подходит библиотека [matplotpib](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiu7ueRm9zgAhWqwcQBHYm4DfcQFjAAegQIFxAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmatplotlib.org%2F&usg=AOvVaw0YgZr7XYZzco6IDaGIE2sw). Там есть все. Если просто список - то `plot(List)`, `scatter(List)`  и пр.